# ASP.NET MVC JQuery error when run without debugger

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project (asp.net mvc). When I run it in debug mode it runs without any error, but if I runs it in release mode (run without debugging) it gives following errors. What could be the issue.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Comment: $ is not defined happens when this piece of core execute before jquery was loaded, but you Will need to provide more code for we to know better

Comment: how are you loading your javascript in? are you using require or just referencing the external js files in the cshtml, or are you placing your script at the bottom of the page, sounds as though the debug is changing the load order of the js to load. Is there an error in the js that causes the rest of the js to fail, is it a path issue, is the path to the js files differently when in debug deployment...just a few ideas, hope they help

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have put min.js files in bundle config file. I removed them and linked directly to cshtml page. Now it's working smoothly.